# Is it possible to create a user defined literal, which converts string literals to an array of own-type?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

Is it possible to create a user defined literal, which converts string literals to an array of own type?

Suppose that I have an own byte type, `mylib::byte`:

```
namespace mylib {
    enum class byte: unsigned char { };
}
```

So, for example, `"Hello"_X` should have the type `mylib::byte[5]`, with the value of `{ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' }`.

---

Here's the background, so maybe you can recommend some other solution.

I have a utf-8 class, which stores a `mylib::byte *`, and a length (this works like `std::string_view`, it doesn't own the memory area):

```
namespace mylib {
    class utf8 {
        const byte *m_string;
        int m_length;
    };
}
```

I'd like to able to construct `mylib::utf8` with string literals in the code conveniently, something like this:

```
mylib::utf8 u = "Hello";
```

Currently, I use `reinterpret_cast`, which is UB:

```
namespace mylib {
    class utf8 {
        const byte *m_string;
        int m_length;

    public:
        utf8(const byte *s) {
            m_string = s;
            m_length = ...;
        }
        utf8(const char *s) {
            m_string = reinterpret_cast<const byte *>(s); // causes UB afterwards
            m_length = ...;
        }
    };
}
```

So I thought, I'd like to have something like this, to avoid UB:

```
mylib::utf8 u = "Hello"_X; // I'd like to have the constructor with `const byte *` to be called here
```

Note: using `mylib::byte` is mandatory, I cannot change it.

Comment: "m_string = reinterpret_cast<const byte *>(s); // causes UB afterwards" why is this ub?

Comment: Arrays aren't copyable, you can't return one by value. You could perhaps return `std::array` - but it will be a temporary, any pointer into it would soon become dangling.

Comment: I think the answer is no in C++17 and yes in C++20. (Though you can't literally have a prvalue of array type, since functions cannot return arrays as prvalues.)

Comment: @Swordfish: because the code will access `const char` as `const byte` afterwards.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: yes, that's a problem. Somehow the compiler should be tricked to create `mylib::byte` array statically.

Comment: @KerrekSB: which feature of C++20 makes this possible?

Comment: @geza: [P0732](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r2.pdf), I believe. The paper even contains a UDL example. I'm not sure this is implemented by any compiler yet, though.

Comment: @KerrekSB: thanks, that proposal seems to solve my problem indeed. Hopefully it gets into C++20.

Comment: @geza your `mylib::byte` is exactly the same as `std::byte` which is, just like its underlying type, allowed to alias. so no ub.

Comment: @Swordfish: and that's the exact reason I don't use `std::byte` :) I know, it would solve this problem. But I'm heading in the way to actually use `mylib::byte` everywhere in my code base, because I almost never use aliasing, I don't want to pay the cost of it. Plus, I think that using `std::byte` because of aliasing would be a hack. That string literal should be `mylib::byte[]` in the first place, not `char[]`, and using aliasing to actually avoid UB.

Comment: @geza I think you got me wrong. What i was saying was not that you should use `std::byte` but that your `mylib::byte` is allowed to alias ;-p

Comment: @Swordfish: ah, sorry :) I don't think so, standard explicitly says `std::byte`, not `enum class XX: unsigned char`. And compilers agree with this, they optimize around `mylib::byte`.

Comment: @Swordfish: `std::byte` is allowed to alias because the standard *says so*, not because it uses `unsigned char` as its underlying type. Everywhere the standard gives an exemption for `char` and `unsigned char`, it also does so for `std::byte`. Not "any enumeration with those as their underlying type", but `std::byte` *specifically*.

Comment: @geza: In C++20, you probably won't need to do this, because `char8_t` will exist. Which is not only explicitly defined to be the return of `u8"SomeText"`, but is specifically *not* allowed to alias. And is specifically unsigned. And the size/alignment of a `char`. And since it isn't an enumeration, it doesn't require quite as much casting.

Comment: @NicolBolas: that would be awesome, thanks for the info, I'll check out `char8_t` support in current compilers right away :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mylib::utf8 operator "" _X(const char* c, std::size_t n) {
  auto* r = new mylib::byte[n];
  std::transform(c, c+n, r, [](auto c){ return (mylib::byte)(unsigned char)(c););
  return {r,n};
}
```

this meets all of your criteria as written; you didn't demand zero leaks.

Comment: "at program startup" should be "whenever `operator "" _X` is called" / "whenever a `""_X` literal is evaluated", should it not?

Comment: Thanks, interesting idea. I'm not sure about this one, though: "it'll just be a few at program startup". Isn't it the case, that `operator "" _X` will be called each time a program reaches it? I mean, for `for (int i=0; i<100; i++) "Hello"_X;`, it is called 100 times, isn't it?

Comment: @geza hmm.  Yes, I was thinking wrong.  And making it true (called once guaranteed) is hard.